# Difference between REST and RPC (with real example)

Tags: rest, rpc

I know this is a common question but I was reading a lot and I feel a bit dumb, I cannot see the real diference

Example from here: 
https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2016/09/understanding-rest-and-rpc-for-http-apis/

[SCENARIO]: kick a user from a chat channel

**RPC**  (correct option, use RPC for this)

```
POST /api/channels.kick HTTP/1.1
Host: slack.com
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "token": "xxxx-xxxxxxxxx-xxxx",
  "channel": "C1234567890",
  "user": "U1234567890"
}
```

**REST** (bad option, REST is not good for this)

```
DELETE /channels/catgifs/users/jerkface HTTP/1.1
Host: api.example.com
```

Now:

**1. Why the first RPC example is not REST? it looks a valid REST to me**

**2. Why is worst the REST alternative?**

(the article says because then we need a different URI for kick, ban, leave... and what is the problem with that? with RPC we need different URL too...)

**Is the difference between RPC and REST only in semantics or "conventions"?**
with RPC we must use verbs on the URL
with REST the URL has no verbs, only resources and the verb is the HTTP method?

Comment: Check out the [architectural constraints](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer#Architectural_constraints) of REST. RPC does not have these constraints (but violating them sacrifices some of the positive characteristics of REST).

Comment: RPC URLs need not be verbs; the operation requested may be represented otherwise, such as in the body of the request as in the SOAP example at your referred article. In fact, RPC is a concept with many flavors of implementation, only a few of which require HTTP as a transport. Generally a goal is that one entity can use code that looks like calling a procedure (method) and another entity can use code that looks like implementing that method, and some software tool or facility creates intermediary layers that transport the method call from the one entity to the other, often over the network...

Comment: When you spell out the HTTP details only, it doesn't look much like conceptual RPC, and if you don't use the intermediary layers to support the method call semantics, it's debatable whether this is RPC at all.